# Laravel echo with Laravel passport auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo, socket.io-redis

i try to create private chat,but on connection i get:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa9b7.png)

my laravel-echo-server.json:

```
{
"authHost": "http://localhost",
"authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
"clients": [
    {
        "appId": "id",
        "key": "key"
    }
],
"database": "redis",
"databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {},
    "sqlite": {
        "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
},
"devMode": true,
"host": null,
"port": "6001",
"protocol": "http",
"socketio": {},
"sslCertPath": "",
"sslKeyPath": "",
"sslCertChainPath": "",
"sslPassphrase": "",
"subscribers": {
    "http": true,
    "redis": true
},
"apiOriginAllow": {
    "allowCors": true,
    "allowOrigin": "http://127.0.0.1",
    "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
    "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
}
```

my bootstrap.js:

```js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
window.io = require('socket.io-client');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
});
```

on postman i check some http api routes and see good answer

can anyone help with it?